# Jacobian in Scala

Tags: r, scala, matrix, calculus, scala-breeze

Is there a way/library to calculate Jacobian in Scala similar to Jacobian function inside `numDeriv` package in R? I am using Breeze, but I was unable to find anything related to Jacobian in it.

For clarity I want to do something like the following in Scala:

```
install.packages("numDeriv")     
library(numDeriv)
logistG <- function(r, p, k, t){
        k * p * exp(r*t) / (k + p * (exp(r*t) - 1))
    }

 a <- function(x, k, deltaT){
 c(r=x[1],logistG(r=x[1], p=x[2], k, deltaT))
      }

k <- 100
p0 <- 0.1*k
r <- 0.2
deltaT <- 0.1
x <- c(r, p0)
A <- jacobian(a, x=x, k=k, deltaT=deltaT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can convert to Scala the following Java code that I wrote once:

```
    public static double[][] computeJacobian(Function<double[], double[]> func, double[] x) {

    double EPS = 1E-6;

    double[] d1 = func.apply(x);
    double[][] J = new double[d1.length][x.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < d1.length; i++) {
        double[] vals = x.clone();
        vals[i] += EPS;
        double[] d2 = func.apply(vals);
        for (int j = 0; j < d1.length; j++) {
            J[j][i] = ((d2[j] - d1[j]) / EPS);
        }
    }
    return J;

}
```